# .on() isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal that pops up and when it's opened again,I'd like the scrollbar to be at the top and not where the user might have left it. I am using .on and scrollTop but its not working. It does however work when I run the line of code in the firebug console.

```
$("#mainContentWindow").on("click", ".question-toggler", function (event) {
    $(".modal-body").scrollTop(0);
    $("#helpSectionDialog").modal('show');


    var helpClass = $("#main-content-pane > div").attr("id");
    $(".help-content").hide();
    $(".help-content." + helpClass).show();
});
```

Comment: run the scrollTop after you show the dialog...

Comment: add a console.log and check if it goes in to the function

Comment: console.log only seems to run once when the page loads and not again when the modal is triggered again

Comment: Are you sure your selectors are correct? It's impossible for us to say whether the code is correct without seeing your HTML

Comment: yeah it works fine when I run the script in the firebug console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this myself using jQuery and Bootstrap. I solved it by adding a handler for the 'shown' event that animated scrollTop immediately (with a duration of 0).

Assuming you have a modal with id 'notice' with a body id of 'noticeBody':

```
// reset notice scrolling
$('#notice').on('shown', function(){
    $('#noticeBody').animate({scrollTop:0}, 0);
});
```

I believe the problem you're seeing is due to an issue moving the scrollbar while the div is hidden, but your mileage may vary (YMMV).